# Vim: Moving around using relativenumber and adding it to the jump list for use with CTRL-O

Tags: vim, gvim

I have relativenumber enabled and often navigate to a specific line by pressing 25k or 7j, etc.  The problem is that after I've changed the line I often find myself wanting to go back to where I was before moving.  So I press CTRL-O but this fails because j/k movements are not added to the movement history.  What happens instead is that I appear to move back twice.

What would be ideal is if Vim added to the move history anytime I perform a j/k operation with a multiplier.  Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a mapping for `j` / `k` that achieves this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> k :<C-U>execute 'normal!' (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k'<CR>
:nnoremap <silent> j :<C-U>execute 'normal!' (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j'<CR>
```

Credit: I've first seen this [here](https://github.com/sunaku/.vim/tree/config).

Comment: This is the one I've been looking for quite many years! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Vim provides any way to add motions to the jumplist, but if you really want to be able to jump back with `''` and treat motions somewhat like jumps, you could do something like this:

```
function! MarkJ()
    mark '
    return "j"
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> j MarkJ()
```

`MarkJ()` manually sets the `'` mark, adding that line to the jumplist (always at column 0, though), and then returns `j` to the mapping. Unfortunately, you would have to do the same for each motion.

I can't think of any way to easily limit this to motions with multipliers, but following the `getchar()` example under [`:help map-expr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-expression), it would theoretically be possible to define a set of functions and mappings that would only call `MarkX()` if the motion follows a multiplier. This is pretty contrived, though, and might become expensive enough to decrease performance.